# Adding a custom path for a Tracesource TextWriterTraceListener output in config

Tags: c#, path, app-config, relative-path, trace

So I'm using Tracesource to log some errors and wan't to create a log file in a users local windows document structure ( something like `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` ).

However I have no idea if I can do anything like that inside a config file.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
        <source name="MainSource"
              switchName="MainSwitch"
              switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" >
            <listeners>
                <add name="LogFileListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="LogFileListener"
           type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="This is the place the output file goes to"
           traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime, Callstack" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
        <add name="MainSwitch" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

initializeData is I think a parameter to the constructor and is where I would have to put a custom path.

Comment: Here is also a more in-depth exploration of how relative path parsing is implemented in Microsoft code: http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/on-textwritertracelistener-inheritance-initializedata-aspnet-and-paths/ And also a workaround is shown in that article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the logfile in the config file is absolute and cannot be assumed by any special variables.

However,  you could create it dynamically and this should solve your issue

[How to: Create and Initialize Trace Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228984.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Below is sample code I was using for my options. It could help you understand the schema.

```
Configuration exeConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

ConfigurationSection diagnosticsSection = exeConfiguration.GetSection("system.diagnostics");

ConfigurationElementCollection switches = diagnosticsSection.ElementInformation
                                                            .Properties["switches"]
                                                            .Value as ConfigurationElementCollection;

foreach (ConfigurationElement switchElement in switches)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("switch: name=" + 
        switchElement.ElementInformation.Properties["name"].Value +
        " value=" + 
        switchElement.ElementInformation.Properties["value"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility of automagically configuring traces (via configuration) given that we are manually _opening_ a configuration file - just like we do in a normal .net application?